# How to write a list of Polygons to a .shp file in Python

Tags: python, shapefile, polygon, geopandas

I create a list of Polygons and MultiPolygons `outmulti` as follows:

```
for pol in polygonToMulti:
    for pol2 in tre:
        if pol.intersects(pol2)==True:
            counter = counter+1
            # If they intersect, create a new polygon that is
            # essentially pol minus the intersection
            nonoverlap = (pol.symmetric_difference(pol2)).difference(pol2)
            outmulti.append(nonoverlap)


finalpol = MultiPolygon(outmulti)
```

I now want to save these Polygons and MultiPolygons of the `outmulti` list in a shp file & then be able to plot and visualize all the objects.
Firstly, I thought of keeping the values of `wkt` into a different list like this:

```
list = []
for i in range(len(outmulti)):
    list.append(outmulti[i].wkt)
```

and then I thought of creating a `GeoDataFrame` having as the `geometry` attribute the above list `list`.

`gdf3=gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=list)`

however this gives a TypeError saying it's not a valid geometry object.

Secondly, I tried creating a GeoDataFrame with a column name "geometry" and then writing all the wkt values of outmulti into that column and then saving the final GeoDataFrame into a file like:

```
#Make list of Polygons -> Geo Data Frame
gdf3=gpd.GeoDataFrame(columns={"geometry"})

for i in range(len(outmulti)):
    temp = gpd.GeoSeries(outmulti[i].wkt)
    gdf3= gdf3.append({'geometry':temp}, ignore_index=True)

    gpd.geometry


gdf3.to_file(filename='dPolygons.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

But in that case I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'has_z'
```

I guess this is because the shp file must have some specific attributes in order to be created, but I cannot understand which and where to get those from.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for the clarification. I edited the question. Is that better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the geometry as a shapely multipolygon/list of polygons. Add it directly to the geodataframe.

```
gdf3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[finalpol])  # Note GeoDataFrame geometry requires a list
gdf3.to_file(filename='dPolygons.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')

# Or

gdf3 = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=outmulti)  # outmulti is already a list
gdf3.to_file(filename='dPolygons.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```